# chown: cannot access 'lisa': No such file or directory

Tags: command-line, 20.04, sudo, chown

```
root@ubuntu:/home/menna# chown root lisa
chown: cannot access 'lisa': No such file or directory
```

I enter this command but it didn't run!

**note: I try to use `sudo` but it didn't run**

**note 2 : lisa is the file's name**

*note 3 :

```
root@ubuntu:/home# ls -l
total 20
-rw-rw-r--  1 menna menna    0 Mar 19 05:43 clark
drwxr-xr-x  2 menna menna 4096 Mar 19 05:08 commands
-rw-rw-r--  1 menna menna    0 Mar 19 05:43 jerry
-rwxrwxrwx  1 menna menna    0 Mar 19 05:43 lisa
drwxrwxrwx 28 menna menna 4096 Mar 19 06:11 menna
drwxrwxr-x  2 menna menna 4096 Mar 19 05:42 seinfeld
drwxrwxr-x  2 menna menna 4096 Mar 19 05:42 superman
drwxrwxr-x  2 menna menna 4096 Mar 19 05:35 thanks*
```

Comment: Where is `lisa`? Did you run `ls` first?

Comment: lisa is the name of the file + yes,, i run `ls`

Comment: Please post output of `ls -l` in `/home/menna` in your question.

Comment: done@ArturMeinild

Comment: You were in the wrong directory. `lisa` is in `/home`, not `/home/menna`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
root@ubuntu:/home/menna
```

is not the same as

```
/home#
```

Please stop using root in an Ubuntu system. You will at some point do something that is irreversible. Use `sudo`.

```
sudo chown root /home/lisa
```

will work.  Another caution: please keep /home where it is intended for: to create a home for users and don't store files in /home itself; user their home to store files for that user. Or make a separate mountpoint if you want to share files between users.